# How to validate for either one or another field in a model using yii1.1?

Tags: php, yii

In a yii@1.1 project, I have a model having a field `event_id` with the rules:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        ['event_id', 'required'],
        ['event_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true],
    ];
}
```

Now I want to extend the table so that there is also a `video_id`.

I am unsure though how I can check for either the `event_id` or the `video_id`. Is this possible through the `rules` method or do I need to add some custom validation?

I don't want to make both fields optional because one of them but not both should be set.

Comment: Related entry in the yii forum: https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/either-or-validation/32417/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`when`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation)

```
['event_id', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
    return $model->video_id === null;
}], 
['video_id', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
    return $model->event_id === null;
}]
```

Looks like it exists only from 2.X ... instead in 1.X you can use this extension https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-conditional-validator

Comment: Shouldn't it be an identical check instead of your not-identity check? I read it as event_id should be required when video_id is not null. But when video_id is not null, event id should be null. I will test it :)

Comment: @k0pernikus yes sorry, I didn't test it.... the point was the `when` clause, but you are right

Comment: The `when` property doesn't exist in Yii 1.x. That's new feature in Yii 2.

Comment: I'm having issues getting the extension to work. If you know how, I appreciate your insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69106834/how-to-register-an-extension-for-yii1-1